# Can't use img tag to insert image from Google Storage with authenticated URL in Gitlab Wiki

Tags: gitlab, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to insert an image into a Gitlab wiki page using an image from Google Storage. When I use the double bracket markdown

`[[authenticated url from Google Storage]]`

the image loads correctly. But when using the following two methods, the image doesn't load correctly on the wiki page:

`![image name](authenticated url from Google Storage)`

`<img src="authenticated url from Google Storage" width="200" height="500">`

Wiki page would show a broken image link icon, and the link of the url would point to something like:

`https://user-content.gitlab-static.net/a9c4c509c56582893770ac5b94af6e72c38322d8/68...d6661696c732f73637265656e73686f74732f494d475f313431342e504e47`

And I would get a `Unsupported content-type returned` error. My guess is that the full link got truncated so the .png is not there anymore.

My main objective is to use the img tag so I can resize the image in the wiki page. Is there any way to achieve that?

I know I can just upload the image to Gitlab wiki and then I can use img tag to specify size. But I'd really rather just point to the files to the Google Storage to save time.

Thanks for the help!

Update:

I tried using an image file on GCP with public internet access (with the googleapis.com URL). Both the `[[URL]]` notation and the `<img>` tag worked and I was able to specify width and height with `img` tag in the Gitlab wiki page.

So my guess is that the Gitlab wiki editor can use GCP authenticated URL when using the `[[URL]]` notation but just can't do it with the `<img>` tag. Probably a bug.

Comment: Can you share your pipeline and how you get your image from GCS? Authentication seems to be the issue.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere If you open the image from within GCS console, you get to the object details page and one of the fields is called Authenticated URL, meaning users with granted permission can use this URL to see the picture. That's the URL I used in Gitlab Wiki page. And when I used `[[URL]]` way with the same URL, the image does load correctly. So I don't think authentication is the issue.